# How to make only the area which the layer is over visible?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm having a hard time explaining what I want to achieve, but I'm making a character in Illustrator that is wearing an helmet. I have made the body of the helmet on a layer behind the characters head. I have also made a face shield on a layer a top of the head  with opacity.

Is there a way to make only the parts of the face that's within the face shield area shown?

[image]

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Benjamin Tried to make an example with my illustration now. Hope it explains what I want to do. I don't want anything of the face be outside the face shield layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Copy the Face Shield - Select it and `Edit > Copy`
2. Hide the existing shield for a moment - `Object > Hide > Selection`
3. Paste in front of the head - Select the head (all of it if it's not already a group) and `Edit > Paste in Front`
4. Select the head and this new pasted shield shape and make a **clipping mask** - `Object > Clipping Mask > Make`
5. Unhide the original shield - `Object > Show All`

I suggest hiding the original shield just so it's not "in the way" for a moment. It's not absolutely mandatory the original shape is hidden though. You could also merely lock the original shield shape to prevent it being mistakenly selected for a moment.

What this does is use the circular shape of the shield to hide anything which is not contained within it. Masking off any additional visible areas, but leaving everything in tact. If you examine the Layers Panel after doing this, you'll see that all your shapes are there, just masked by the new (shield) path.